# ltspice .param if statement

Tags: ltspice, if

Super simple question here. Is it possible to use an if statement in a .param LTSpice directive? If so, what is the syntax? Shown below does not function.

[image]

Note that the .step function can not be used for my purposes, to the best of my knowledge, because I want to simulate a step response over time.

Comment: If it's about using an `if()` inside a `.param`, yes, it's possible. If it's about using the keyword `time` inside a `.param`, no. As I said [back then](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247396/ltspice-param-if-statement#comment552497_248891), it is possible to use a `.func` for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For those of you coming across this question several years late, it looks like this is indeed actually possible if instead of `.param` you use the `.func` directive.

Just do `.func R(t) if(t>0.5,1,2)` and `R = R(time)`.
[image: LTSpice XVII Setup]

And it works!
[image: Transient Simulation Results]
(Tested in LTSpice XVII)

Comment: Brilliant! I’ve been using LTspice for 10 years and have never seen this before.

Comment: Anyone looking at this answer and being excited will be interested in: 

http://ltwiki.org/?title=B_sources_%28complete_reference%29

Comment: If you have defined tolerance or power rating, LTSpice will complain about "unknown paramter "tol/pwr"". Just delete the value and that should fix it. Looks like a bug in field separation in GUI (https://groups.io/g/LTspice/topic/50267146 for reference)

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, the `.PARAM` directive is evaluated at startup. The answer to your *literal* question is thus ***no***.

You can, however, put the equation as the resistance:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @pipe. This is the answer I feared. What if I'm evaluating eight other parameters based on my first? I'm actually trying to simulate the step response from a brushless DC motor, and only used this simple example to illustrate my question. I suppose I could calculate the results outside of LTSpice and put if statements in the model where appropriate.

Comment: @BrianDohler Yeah, can't help with that I'm afraid, I hope you find a solution. It would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can, put it in curly braces like so: `.param R = {if(time>0.5,1,2)}` and set the value of R1 to `{R}`.

You can also make more complex statements like this:

`.param MODE 1
.param FREQ {if(MODE == 0, 1000, if(MODE == 1, 500, if(MODE == 2,250)))}`.

This will select a `FREQ` based on the given `MODE`.

Comment: Did you try it? This does not work in my LTspice, but perhaps it's a new feature. I have't upgraded in a year.

Comment: I used it in LTSpice IV and LTSpice XVII to simulate a function generator. My voltage source is controlled like this: `PULSE({Vinitial} {Von} [...] {Tperiod})` where each parameter is defined in a block of `.param`s, like this: `.param Vinitial = {if(MODE==2, 0, 1)}`. What might be important is that `.param`s in one text block are processed top to bottom, i.e. `MODE` needs to be defined before `Vinitial`.

Comment: Here's the [schematic](http://www.webcodesign.de/LTSpiceFunctionGenerator.png).

Comment: But you don't use `IF(time>0.5,1,2)` anywhere. `time` is a special variable, and the problem here is that `time` is not evaluated in a `.PARAM` statement. OP wants to have a time-dependent resistance without embedding it into the actual resistor.

Comment: Oh darn, I've expected that `time` will be parsed. Hmm, I guess not because it constantly changes but parameters are only evaluated once at the beginning of the simulation. I don't think it'll work but might be worth a try: store `time` in a parameter (`.param T time`) and then use `T` rather than `time`.

Comment: @Tox You can forget about using `time` in a `.param` statement. `time` cannot be "stored" anywhere, since it's continuously changing. It can be used in `.func` declarations, though, directly or indirectly. What you meant with `R=function(time)` only applies to behavioural resistors, and thus it's an expression to be used *as is* inside the `Value` field (of the appropiate element).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, so it is as I expected. :/ That's a shame.

Answer (score 0):

R=table(time,0.5,2,0.501.1)

R=table(time,t1,R1,t2,R2)

from 0 to t1 R value = R1; 
from t1 to t2 R changes lineally from R1 to R2, then 
R value will remain equal to R2 till the end