# Gradually Varying PWM in PSPICE

Tags: pwm, simulation, pspice

How do I gradually vary the pulse width in the "VPULSE" model? I tried using parametric sweep but it does not produce the correct waveform or I don't know how to do a parametric sweep in transient mode. Here is a screenshot of the schematic. I want the "PW" to vary from 1u to 15u gradually so that I can see the capacitor voltage waveform with respect to time.
[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/377905/95619) help?

Comment: It does help. So I do need additional circuit to realise the gradually varying pulse width. It should work with PSPICE.